# French resources for daily phrases with video or any visual contents

Tags: expressions, ressources

Stack Exchangers, I hope all in future accomplished.

I'm looking for such materials mentioned above, for I'm an elementary French learner and have been adding and adding words, repeatedly on anki cards; I was creating those flash cards. And I thought now it might be stimulating to start expanding leaning to sentences so was searching such contents available online, but I end up here with no luck.

The flash cards, I'm generating, have pics instead of translations cause that's my tactic here; I decided to learn French with monolingual environment. That's how I want it and the key which makes it hard to meet my desire.

Hope you, watching this and some of whom, can help. But thanks for your time anyway.

Happy learning.

-Ethe

Answer (score 3):

["Le Point du FLE"](http://www.lepointdufle.net/) and ["Français Facile"](http://www.francaisfacile.com/) are websites you can look at for these things.
 They are very  helpful.

Comment: @Papa Poule merci pour les modifications.